# Making an editor page with sections doesnt work (eclipse, java)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to create a multipage editor looking similar to the manifest editor. I used the wizard for multipage editors, and tried to make a really really simple page following the [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Forms33/index.html)

```
 void createPage0() {

    Composite composite = new Composite(getContainer(), SWT.DEFAULT);

    FormToolkit toolkit = new FormToolkit(composite.getDisplay());
    ScrolledForm scrollform= toolkit.createScrolledForm(composite);
    scrollform.setText("Test Viewer");

    toolkit.decorateFormHeading(form.getForm());

    int index = addPage(composite);
    setPageText(index, "editor1");
}
```

If I run this in eclipse, the first page of the editor is plain grey with nothing displayed. (There suppose to be the title according to the tutorial)

Does anyone know why it doesn't work?

Comment: Where are you calling `createPage0`?

Comment: @greg-449 in protected void createPages() {createPage0();}  int he class public class MappingEditor extends MultiPageEditorPart implements IResourceChangeListener (created with the multipage editor wizard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a layout on the `Composite` so that it fills the data area:

```
Composite composite = new Composite(getContainer(), SWT.NONE);

composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());
```

If you want to use the `FormToolkit` code a lot then `FormEditor` provides more support for this.

Comment: I have another problem now...  The scrolled form has two scroll active scroll bars although there is obviously nothing to scroll. I changed it to Form with createForm, but it still has active scroll bars... Could you help out with this one too?

Comment: A new problem should be a new Question.

Comment: Going to do it :) Thansk for the advice, new here :)

Answer (score 0):

you should override `addPages()`.

JavaDoc says:
Subclass should implement this method to add pages to the editor using `addPage(IFormPage)` method.

Comment: `createPages` is correct for `MultiPageEditorPart`, `addPages` for `FormEditor`.